# Render dynamic menu in every view

Tags: python, django

I have a few views and everyone has to render dynamic menu like this:

```
def view1(request):
   return render_to_response('view1.html', 
                             RequestContext(request, {'menu': menu, 'a': a, ...}))

def view2(request):
   return render_to_response('view2.html', 
                             RequestContext(request, {'menu': menu, 'b': b, ...}))

def view3(request):
   return render_to_response('view3.html', 
                             RequestContext(request, {'menu': menu, 'c': c, ...}))

def viewN(request):
   return render_to_response('view4.html',
                             RequestContext(request, {'menu': menu, 'd': d, ...}))
```

But it is incomfortable beacuse I have to add menu attribute to every view. In which way can I do the optimization of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) are for. You're already using RequestContext, so you just need to define a function that returns your menu and add it to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of django you are using, you might want to look into [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) or even class based [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/).

Otherwise you can also do something like:

```
def menu_view(request, template='menu.html', **kwargs)
    return render_to_response(template, kwargs, 
           context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I think kwargs should work just like that. Haven't tested. If it doesn't, make a dictionary out of it.